# Не работает register_next_step_handler в pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telebot

Пишу бота для заказов. Требуется создать ветвь по командам, делаю через кнопки. Нашел метод register_next_step_handler , пытался запустить - не работает. Даже примеры из интернета не работают. Буду благодарен за помощь!.

```
    import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('5433971032:AAGV2z3PmFA_OvR07-pIEwGbS2YNKrHAclk')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def beginning(message):
    hello_user = 'Здравствуй , '
    if message.from_user.last_name is None:
        hello_user += f'{message.from_user.first_name}'
    else:
        hello_user += f'{message.from_user.first_name}{message.from_user.last_name}'
    mes = bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text=hello_user)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(mes, callback=choose_action)


def choose_action(message):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='Пожалуйста,выберите действие!')
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    Menu = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Посмотреть меню')
    Order = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=' Сделать заказ')
    keyboard.add(Menu, Order)



bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте так

```
bot.register_next_step_handler(mes, choose_action)
```

А еще у вас `choose_action` в целом ничего не делает.

```
keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
Menu = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Посмотреть меню', callback_data="check_menu")
Order = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=' Сделать заказ', callback_data="create_order")
keyboard.add(Menu, Order)

bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='Пожалуйста,выберите действие!', reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Ну и дальше ловите колбек от кнопки

Comment: Здравствуйте , исправил код но все равно не работает(((

Comment: Что значит "не работает"?

Comment: Вы вообще понимаете как работает `register_next_step_handler`?

Comment: Не переходит на другую функцию внутри обработчика

Comment: Оно перейдет только если юзер напишет сообщение